# RegEx to reduce the decimal places to 5 digits in notepad++

Tags: regex, compression, notepad++, geojson

I am trying to reduce the size of a geoJSON file so my website viewers can view the maps in page very quickly.

You can find more information about geoJSON format here http://geojson.org/

I read a blog suggesting to reduce the number of digits after decimal places in a GeoJSON file using notepad ++.

I can find answers for removing all decimal places in a number. But my question is I want to preserve the first 5 decimal places in a number and remove the others.

EG: -103.3751447563353

After replacing: -103.37514

**Edit:**
I tried the answers but my notepad++ says "can't find the text". I have ensured regular expression checkbox is checked but still no luck
This will save more than 10 characters for each latitude or longitude co-ordinates.

Please share your answers

Comment: Are there only numbers in your file? For example, there are no IP addresses?

Comment: no ip address, it has characters for state name and decimals for lat and lng coordinates

Comment: What is the pattern you tried and why didn't it work?

Comment: I can search with reg ex but my requirement is to replace them. I dont know what character or regex will help in replacing

Comment: @Kira, to provide you relevant help, we need to know what works for you and hoow. So, there is a regex that matches the numbers. What is it? All the answers below can trim numbers like `3243253.45345465435`, in *any* context, do you need this?

Comment: Find `\d\.\d{5}\K\d+` replace with nothing. But, the real problem doing this is rounding of the 6th digit. But, since it's past 5 decimal places it might not be off by more than a half mile or so.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I have used the provided answers but the problem is notepadd++ is not matching the numbers. It says "Can't find the text "(?<=\d\.\d{5})\d+".  I have checked the regular expression checkbox but still no luck maybe there is some other settings I need to change in notepad++

Comment: See https://imgur.com/a/cDeGk. It works well.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, the problem turns out to be in old version of notepad++ (5.x.x) version. After upgrading the given answer is working good

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/Jxf8ZP/2)

```
(?<=\d\.\d{5})\d+
```

- `(?<=\d\.\d{5})` Positive lookbehind ensuring what precedes is a digit, dot, and then 5 digits
- `\d+` Matches one or more digits (this is what will be replaced)

Replace with nothing

---

Another alternative. [See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/Jxf8ZP/3)

```
\d+\.\d{5}\K\d+
```

- `\d+` Match one or more digits
- `\.` Match the dot character literally
- `\d{5}` Match any digit exactly 5 times
- `\K` Resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match
- `\d+` Matches one or more digits (this is what will be replaced)

Replace with nothing

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following Regex : [`(\d+\.\d{5})\d*`](https://regex101.com/r/EI9JBc/4)

`\d+` looks for any number of digits.

`\.` looks for the character `.`

`\d{5}` lets 5 digits through

`\d*` looks for the remaining digits

You can then use `$1`.